# Will there be a clean upgrade path from 10.10 to 11.04?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, unity, 11.04

Will there be a straight upgrade path from 10.10 to 11.04 (Gnome to Unity), and will there be measures put in place to ensure that Gnome is properly "cleaned" out on the way?

Comment: Actually, I hope *GNOME* doesn't get "cleaned out", as that would be data loss for those people who want to keep using GNOME.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unity is simply a new shell for Gnome and will probably be installed as part of the current ubuntu-desktop metapackage. This means that upon upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 Unity will be installed by default with the upgrade.

I am assuming that Gnome 2 is planned to be installed as well, so users both upgrading and freshly installing will get both, just Unity by default.

Comment: I'd like to confirm both that the Gnome2 experience will be installed everywhere alongside the Unity shell, and that we consider Unity to be a shell for GNOME. As we move to GNOME 3 applications, we'll preserve the GNOME 2 shell environment as a 2D experience as long as possible.

Answer (score 4):

We will of course provide an upgrade path, I don't know what you mean by "cleaned" so please provide more detail in your question.

Comment: My apologies. NightwishFan answered my question above.  I believed that Unity was going to be "developed" into a Desktop Environment on it's own, versus it being a "shell" for Ubuntu.

Comment: I definitely will, as soon as my 10 minute wait is up :)

Answer (score 2):

In the past when we have major such changes (metacity to compiz, for example) to the defaults upgrades kept their current settings and new installs got the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Having just upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04, it has replaced my 'old' desktop with Unity.  Have had a loooong search to find out how to replace it (SystemSettings->System->LoginScreen - switch to 'Ubuntu Classic')

Comment: It shouldn't take you that long, next time just ask here!

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the statement was that "Unity will be the default UI for clean installs on hardware that will give a satisfactory performance" (or something like that), so that suggests that if you do an in-place upgrade, you will stick with stock GNOME

Comment: My answer might be wrong then if the statement was "Clean install". Do you have a source?

Comment: @NightwishFan Here's Mark's keynote if you want the details: http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/file/4294234/